# Independent Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

What does it mean for spaces to be independent?

[image]

Comment: I'm looking at (b) and wondering.

Comment: This is from Artin's *Algebra*.

Comment: Page 95 if that's of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subspaces $W_1,...,W_k$ of $V$ are said to be *independent* if the only combination $$w_1+\cdots+w_k=0$$ with each $w_j\in W_j$ is $w_1=\cdots=w_k=0$. (This definition should be a bit earlier on the page.)

Comment: Do you have some literature/references/etc.?

Comment: You get the idea?

Comment: @Trancot: In my version of Artin, it's just a bit earlier on the page.

Comment: Ha ha ha! Wow, OK. Yes, I didn't see that. Is yours the second edition? Mine is...

Comment: @Trancot: No worries. It happens. Artin's pretty good about only using terminology that he has defined. I believe mine is 2nd edition, yes.

Answer (score 1):

That a vector space $V$ and $W$ are (linearly) independent means you can not write any element of $V$ in terms of a linear combination of elements of $W$ and also consider the same condition replacing $V$ and $W$.

As an example, see the impossibility of writing a non-zero vector on the $x$-axis in terms of some elements on the $y$-axis.

Comment: In other words?

Comment: You know what a linear combination is?

Comment: I was looking for Cameron's point of view. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector space $V$, we say that a collection of subspaces $\{W_1, \dots, W_k\}$ is independent if for every $1 \le i \le k$,

$$W_i \cap \sum_{j \ne i} W_j = \{0\}$$

In other words, no nonzero vector in $W_i$ can be a linear combination of vectors from the other subspaces.